# How to track user details when session expires?

Tags: xdb

Is there any possibility to track the session expired users or logged out users? When a user visits without login details how can I track the user details?

Answer (score 1):

When their session expires, the Sitecore cookie is still there. So you can still track them when they come back.

For logout, just make sure you specify the false in `Analytics.Tracker.Current.EndVisit(false);`. This tells Sitecore not to delete the analytics cookie. Then you can track them even after they log out.

```
    public void Logout()
    {
        var user = AuthenticationManager.GetActiveUser();
        AuthenticationManager.Logout();
    }

    public void HardLogout(HttpSessionStateBase session)
    {
        this.Logout();
        session.Abandon();
        Analytics.Tracker.Current.EndVisit(false);
        Analytics.Tracker.Current.EndTracking();
    }
```